# Python Question: What is the time complexity of using `itertools.islice` on `collections.deque`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, time-complexity, slice

As you know, `collections.deque` does not support regular slicing in Python, and so I have to use `itertools.islice` instead.

However, I know that index access to elements in `collections.deque` are not constant time in general (they are linear in terms of how far away the index is from the head/tail).

**If I want to get the last N elements of a `deque`. What is the time complexity of `itertools.islice(deque, len(deque) - N, len(deque))`? How is `itertools.islice` implemented?**

Comment: It's linear, itertools islice simply iterates over the collection

Comment: If you want to see how islice is implemented, you can check the source code, it is in C. But in the itertools docs they provide an equivalent Python version: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

Comment: A faster approach is likely ```itertools.islice(reversed(deque), N)``` because it doesn't need to skip the first elements. Not to be confused with ```deque.reverse()```

Comment: @Homer512 Got it. Yea. Your approach looks better.